# TextInput weird behaviour in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following `TextInput`,

```
<TextInput
        style={[
          styles.inputField,
          isEmailError && { borderColor: color.delete },
        ]}
        placeholder={'E-mail'}
        placeholderTextColor={color[colorScheme].textMuted}
        autoCapitalize={'none'}
        autoCorrect={false}
        value={userCredentials.email}
        onChangeText={onChangeEmail}
        onSubmitEditing={passwordInput.current && passwordInput.current.focus}
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        returnKeyType={'next'}
        keyboardType="email-address"
/>
```

When I click anywhere else outside the keyboard(let's say a button), the expected behaviour is that the button will get clicked, however, in here, first click always closes the keyboard then I have to press again for whatever element i was trying to reach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of scroll view. Add props `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` in your scrollview as below to solve error :

```js
<ScrollView
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
    keyboardDismissMode="interactive"
>

...
...

</ScrollView>
```

You can find more detail [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
import DismissKeyboard from 'dismissKeyboard';
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>{DismissKeyboard()}}>
    <View style={Styles.container}>
       <TextInput />
    </View>
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: What is DismissKeyboard and how should this help? Please provide an explanation.